# Double for statement in list comprehension

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letterlist = [ ]
```

To list all the characters in all the words, we can do this:

```
letterlist = [word[i] for word in wordlist for i in range(len(word))]

['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'i', 't']
```

However, when I try to do it in this way:

```
letterlist = [character for character in word for word in wordlist]
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'word' is not defined on line 9
```

Can someone explain my error in understanding how list comprehension works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing

```
wordlist   = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
letterlist = [character for character in word for word in wordlist]
```

is comparable to the following nested loop:

```
wordlist   = ["cat", "dog", "rabbit"]
letterlist = []

for character in word:

    for word in wordlist:

        letterlist.append(character)
```

This loop will throw the same error as your list comprehension because you are attempting to reference `character in word` before defining `word` as an element of `wordlist`. You just have the order backwards. Try the following:

```
letterlist = [character for word in wordlist for character in word]
```

Comment: @Kane In list comprehensions, just like in normal nested loops, you have specify the outer loop first.